# Error while running vnc server

Tags: solaris, vnc

When I try to run vncserver in my machine, I can see following errors -

```
vncserver: couldn't find "Xvnc" on your PATH.
vncserver: couldn't find "xauth" on your PATH.
```

The command I executed is

```
>vncserver
```

The OS I am using is

```
SunOS hostname 5.10 Generic_150400-20 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
```

I tried to search with google but couldn't find a proper solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vncserver` is a script that runs `Xvnc`. You're missing Xvnc, which is kind of... out of date. RealVNC seems to ignore that it ever had a free software version.

It's here, though: http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/ports/distfiles/xc/vnc-4_1_3-unixsrc.tar.gz

Tightvnc and Tigervnc are more modern versions of Xvnc; I believe symbolic linking Xvnc to one of these servers would work as well.

I'll keep looking for information, because I had to deal with this once but my memories aren't very clear. I hope this gets you on the right track, at least.

I don't have any experience with solaris specifically, but I believe you can get it installed via `pkg`, based on some searching:

```
pkg install --accept solaris-desktop
```

I think that command is likely to also fix the missing `xauth`.

Comment: The `pkg install` command given is correct for Solaris 11 (SunOS 5.11), but won't work on the much older Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.10) which still uses the ancient SVR4 packaging system.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the VNC software that's part of Solaris 10, make sure your $PATH includes both `/usr/openwin/bin` and `/usr/X11/bin` before you run `vncserver`.